# Ruby: Formatting table data to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, chap-links-library

I'm trying to make a timeline for an the bugs and updates for an open source project. I'm new to ruby, but I'm getting some experience gradually.

I've created a table called historical_gems, with the following code in the model:

```
class HistoricalGem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :build_date, :version
  belongs_to :ruby_gem, :foreign_key => :gem_id
end
```

I'm using a JS Plugin (http://almende.github.com/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc) that requires objects with two field names ('start' for the date and 'content' for the title) in the JSON Array to display the timeline using JS.

I believe I have to do something like this in the controller which defines my timeline method to render the JSON:

```
def timelinem
@name = params[:id]
@rpm = AbcTable.find_by_name(@name)
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @rpm.json_timelines }
   end
end
```

Then I probably would have to define a 'json_timelines' method inside my model, maybe something like:

```
def json_timelines(gems = [])
    dates = []
    gem_id.each { |p|
        gems << p
        dates << p.build_date(gems)
    end
   }
 end
```

I'm only starting out with RoR, and even after hours with guides and tutorials and debugging, I'm not able to put together this code. Can anyone help me out, please? I don't think I'm doing it right.

btw, don't be too harsh if I overlooked something obvious, I'm only 16 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `render :json => ...` in your code should work fine (but with `HistoricalGem` instead of `AbcTable`) as long as `json_timelines` returns an object that's serializable as JSON (e.g., an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) or a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html)).

Try something like this for your method definition:

```
def json_timelines(gems = [])
  gems.map do |g|
    {
      :content => g.title,
      :date    => g.build_date
    }
  end
end
```

The above snippet assumes your "historical_gems" table has "title" and "build_date" columns; if not, adjust the code to reflect the fields you actually want represented in your JSON.

Comment: Thanks! Can I render the json to a particular file, so that I can request it from the view, and the request invokes another method which puts the generated JSON into /stats/gemname/jsonfile.json ? Is there a way I can achieve this with the json_timelines function itself?